# Xamarin.Forms android app - event handler keeping PageModel referenced despite being unsubscribed

Tags: events, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms

We've got a Xamarin.Forms Android app in which we're displaying progress on a loading page, the progress value being sent by an event from another class.

We're using FreshMvvm which has ViewIsAppearing and ViewIsDisappearing overrides available in the PageModel.

So we're subscribing on ViewIsAppearing, and unsubscribing in ViewIsDisappearing - we're also unsubscribing in a PrepareForDispose method which is intended to ensure the PageModel has cleaned up so that it can be disposed.

Code is  below. ProgressManager is supplied by IoC

```
        protected override void ViewIsAppearing (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.ViewIsAppearing (sender, e);

            ProgressManager.ProgressEvent += ProgressManager_ProgressEvent;

        }

        protected override void ViewIsDisappearing (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.ViewIsDisappearing (sender, e);

            RemoveEventHandlers();
        }

        public override void PrepareForDispose()
        {
            RemoveEventHandlers();
            base.PrepareForDispose();
        }

        private void RemoveEventHandlers()
        {
            ProgressManager.ProgressEvent -= ProgressManager_ProgressEvent;
        }
```

The problem is that, when examining object in Profiler, we can see the LoadingPageModel is still in memory, because of the *EventArgs* created in the *ViewIsAppearing* (examining the "Paths To Root" in Profiler tells us this).

When I log/debug the app, I can see that *RemoveEventHandlers* has been called.

So is _ProgressManager.ProgressEvent -= ProgressManager_ProgressEvent;_ failing to remove the handler, or is there another reason that we've still got a reference to the PageModel from the EventArgs?

*Edit* One possibility is that we're subscribing more than once, but unsubscribing only once. I've checked with debug/logging, and I don't think this is the case. We're subscribing/unsubscribing symmetrically.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we were subscribing twice (due to the lifecyle of the page in question at the start of the app lifecycle). Therefore the single unsubscribe was leaving a subscription behind.

Fixing this fixed the problem.